# How do I use a 4GB USB flash drive to install Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, usb, system-installation, windows-7, wubi

I've downloaded "ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64" and used Pen Drive Linux to get it onto my USB.  I then restarted my computer (a Windows 7 Home Premium edition) and entered the boot menu to have it boot from the Sandisk USB (it called it Sandisk Cruzer Cruzer).  Linux came up and asked if I wanted to try or install.  I picked install, connected to my Wi-Fi, and installed it.  After my laptop restarted, Windows booted immediately.  I have tried several times and cannot get a choice between the two.

P.S.
I have used the Windows Installer, Wubi, but at the last second it gave me some kind of error.

Comment: Why don't you boot from the USB again, this time select "Try Ubuntu" and from the desktop run the http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and edit your answer with the results (or a pastebin link).

Comment: Did your PC come with UEFI?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you should remove any current Ubuntu or Wubi installation.
2. Next download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), an easy tool for creating bootable USBs.
3. Download the prefered Ubuntu image from [Ubuntu Download Section](http://ubuntu.com/download).
4. Open *Rufus* and write the image on the USB (it is very easy).
5. Reboot your PC after finishing, and change the boot order to boot from USB.
6. Once the installation window comes up, click *Install Now*.
7. Lastly, choose *Run Ubuntu **alongside** Windows 7*.

I'm pretty sure there will be a bootloader in order to choose between the two OSes.

Comment: It doesn't sound like there's anything wrong with the USB. Just the installation of grub failed or was incorrect e.g. BIOS style boot on UEFI computer, or grub installed in the wrong disk MBR. If the USB was bad, it would unlikely have completed the entire installation to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is most likely installed, but you're possibly automatically booting to the Windows partition immediately. If that's the case:

1. Reboot your computer
2. Go to your BIOS settings
3. Select your other drive, or if you used UEFI and installed to the same disk (not recommended) then highlight "Ubuntu" and boot to that.

If you automatically boot to the grub bootloader it will give you the option to pass through to Windows whereas Windows will not do the vice versa. This functionality does not occur automatically during installation though.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Boot loader for your Linux OS and Windows are on separate disks and you windows boot loader is prioritized to be loaded first. You can press the boot option keys (You may find your's [here](http://www.disk-image.com/faq-bootmenu.htm)). When you are on the boot loader screen select the corresponding Disk for Ubuntu. And if you want to make **Ubuntu** load first, then go to your BIOS or UEFI settings and change the boot order.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can also use the **Universal USB Installer** if you have through windows.
It is more easy that way.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.